# Critical values of a map to a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to S$ be open proper holomorphic map, $X$ a complex manifold and $S$ a Riemann surface. Is it then true that the critical values $C\subset S$ of  $f$ are a discrete supset?

So far I only noted that this would be true, if the set of critical points $K\subset X$ was discrete. But I don't know how to prove it. If $X$ was also a Riemann surface, I could apply the identity principle to $f'$, but in the general case I don't know how to proceed.

Edit: I know about Sard's theorem. I don't see why it is strong enough though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem

Comment: @AlanMuniz: In the smooth category, the set of critical values can be dense, in fact (still of measure 0).

Comment: Sure... The fact that the map is proper and holomorphic is crucial.

Comment: In this case, if $A\subset X$ is an analytic subvariety, then $f(A) \subset S$ will be an analytic subvariety. See page 162 of  Gunning & Rossi book Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables.

Comment: I don't have access to the book mentionned by Alan Muniz, but I think he is refering to Remmert's theorem (if $f: X \to Y$ is proper holomorphic, then the image of an analytic set is an analytic subset of $Y$).